# How can I get a list of all enqueued scripts and styles?

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style, scripts, css

I'm creating a plugin and I want to get the list of all scripts and CSS used by other plugins.

This is my function:

```
function crunchify_print_scripts_styles() {    
    $result = [];
    $result['scripts'] = [];
    $result['styles'] = [];

    // Print all loaded Scripts
    global $wp_scripts;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $script ) :
       $result['scripts'][] =  $wp_scripts->registered[$script]->src . ";";
    endforeach;

    // Print all loaded Styles (CSS)
    global $wp_styles;
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $style ) :
       $result['styles'][] =  $wp_styles->registered[$style]->src . ";";
    endforeach;

    return $result;
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'crunchify_print_scripts_styles');
```

I want to get the returned value inside a variable.

I tried this:

```
$toto = do_action( 'crunchify_print_scripts_styles' );
var_dump( $toto );
```

And this is my result:

```
NULL
```

If I write `echo` inside every `foreach` loop, I get the correct results, but how to store these values inside a variable?

[edit]

My code inside a pluginm which is not working too

```
/**
 *  Get all scripts and styles from Wordpress
 */
function print_scripts_styles() {

    $result = [];
    $result['scripts'] = [];
    $result['styles'] = [];

    // Print all loaded Scripts
    global $wp_scripts;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $script ) :
        $result['scripts'][] =  $wp_scripts->registered[$script]->src . ";";
    endforeach;

    // Print all loaded Styles (CSS)
    global $wp_styles;
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $style ) :
        $result['styles'][] =  $wp_styles->registered[$style]->src . ";";
    endforeach;

    return $result;
}

add_action( 'wp_head', 'wp_rest_assets_init');

/**
 * Init JSON REST API Assets routes.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
function wp_rest_assets_init() {


    $all_the_scripts_and_styles = print_scripts_styles();

    if ( ! defined( 'JSON_API_VERSION' ) &&
         ! in_array( 'json-rest-api/plugin.php', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) {
             $class = new WP_REST_Assets();
             $class::$scriptsAndStyles = $all_the_scripts_and_styles;
             add_filter( 'rest_api_init', array( $class, 'register_routes' ) );
    } else {
        $class = new WP_JSON_Menus();
        add_filter( 'json_endpoints', array( $class, 'register_routes' ) );
    }
}


add_action( 'init', 'wp_rest_assets_init' );
```

Comment: `do_action` does not return a result, and besides, the action has already taken place at `wp_enqueue_scripts` ... easier just to create a global, eg. `global $crunchifyenqueued; $crunchifyenqueued = $result;` then again call the global in your later function to access the variable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it didn't solve the problem, the response for var_dump($crunchifyenqueued) is "NULL".

Comment: so why not use `apply_filters` then? you can easily get the return value from that.

Comment: I already tried, I can't save the result inside a variable.

Comment: of course you can by using a global?

Comment: It doesn't work too

Comment: from where on earth does `endforeach;` comes in such codes??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`do_action` doesn't quite work like that.  When you call `do_action('crunchify_print_scripts_styles')` WP looks at its list of registered actions and filters for any that are attached to a hook called `crunchify_print_scripts_styles` and then runs those functions.

And you probably want to remove this:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'crunchify_print_scripts_styles');
```

... because you aren't able to get the return result of your function.

Also when you use this particular hook you can't guarantee that other functions don't enqueue more scripts or styles *after* you've generated your list.  Use a hook that fires after all scripts and styles have been enqueued, such as wp_head, for convenience, or better still just call your function within your theme when you want to display the result.

Reworking your code like this should work...

```
function crunchify_print_scripts_styles() {

    $result = [];
    $result['scripts'] = [];
    $result['styles'] = [];

    // Print all loaded Scripts
    global $wp_scripts;
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $script ) :
       $result['scripts'][] =  $wp_scripts->registered[$script]->src . ";";
    endforeach;

    // Print all loaded Styles (CSS)
    global $wp_styles;
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $style ) :
       $result['styles'][] =  $wp_styles->registered[$style]->src . ";";
    endforeach;

    return $result;
}
```

Then within your theme:

```
print_r( crunchify_print_scripts_styles() );
```

... will show you the results for debugging, or of course...

```
$all_the_scripts_and_styles = crunchify_print_scripts_styles();
```

... will give you the list to manipulate.

Calling it in the theme makes sure you call it after all scripts and styles are enqueued.

To call it from your plugin, attach it to any hook that runs later than wp_enqueue_scripts, like wp_head as I mentioned above:

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'wpse_233142_process_list');

function wpse_233142_process_list() {

    $all_the_scripts_and_styles = crunchify_print_scripts_styles();
    // process your array here

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Andy, but what I want to do is to get these values inside a plugin. My plugin will return these values under a json format.

Comment: Then put `$all_the_scripts_and_styles = crunchify_print_scripts_styles();` inside your plugin!  Tweaked the answer to suit.

Comment: It doesn't work, both scripts and styles are empty. It seems like `global wp_scripts` `global wp_styles` are totally empty. But they work with a `do_action or apply_filters`

Comment: Are you calling your function later than the `wp_enqueue_scripts` action as I recommended originally?

Comment: I've expanded the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: DAMMMMNNN? Thank you very much, it is working FINE !!!!!!!! How can I implement this new function `wpse_233142_process_list` inside my plugin? Does it need to have the same name?

Comment: Rename it to what you want, as long as you rename it in the filter call too. And feel free to accept the answer ;-)

Comment: Ok sorry, but this is working fine inside a theme, but not inside a plugin. I'm searching the reason, once found I will share my result.

Comment: If all your code runs off hooks there should be zero difference really.

Comment: I updqted my initial post with my plugin main code, if you want to take a look at it...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43071/discussion-between-edouard-kombo-and-andy-macaulay-brook).

Comment: Can't chat right now.  But it looks as though you are calling your function on two different hooks and when you call it on `init` then none of the scripts or styles will have been enqueued.  I haven't looked at the REST API at all, so I glaze over there, but you need to call my code as late as we discussed.  Also remember that none of the scripts and styles are needed or wanted on an API call, so it's possible that none are enqueued in that context and so you won't have any to list.

Comment: I'm searching now how to make my hooks execute in last, because I don't see any other solution

Answer (score 17):

You could use [`wp_print_scripts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_print_scripts/) and [`wp_print_styles`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_print_styles/) actions to **timely and properly** access to enqueued scripts and styles, as these actions are the last events before scripts and styles are included in the document and, because of that, the last event where modifications on `$wp_styles` or `$wp_scripts` could have effect on styles and scripts included in the document.

So, they are the events where you can be more confident that `$wp_styles` and `$wp_scripts` contain the scripts and styles effectively included in the document.

```
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'cyb_list_scripts' );
function cyb_list_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    $enqueued_scripts = array();
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) {
        $enqueued_scripts[] = $wp_scripts->registered[$handle]->src;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'cyb_list_styles' );
function cyb_list_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    $enqueued_styles = array();
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ) {
        $enqueued_styles[] = $wp_styles->registered[$handle]->src;
    }
}
```

If you declare `$enqueued_scripts` adn `$enqueued_styles` as global variables (or any other valid scope, for example you could store it in a method's property), you could access to the list of script and styles in a later action.

For example (just a quick example):

```
global $enqueued_scripts;
global $enqueued_styles;

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'cyb_list_scripts' );
function cyb_list_scripts() {
    global $wp_scripts;
    global $enqueued_scripts;
    $enqueued_scripts = array();
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) {
        $enqueued_scripts[] = $wp_scripts->registered[$handle]->src;
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'cyb_list_styles' );
function cyb_list_styles() {
    global $wp_styles;
    global $enqueued_styles;
    $enqueued_styles = array();
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ) {
        $enqueued_styles[] = $wp_styles->registered[$handle]->src;
    }
}

add_action( 'wp_head', function() {
    global $enqueued_scripts;
    var_dump( $enqueued_scripts );
    global $enqueued_styles;
    var_dump( $enqueued_styles );
} );
```

Answer (score 2):

my solution for this is :

- make an option field in db
- activate sessions and secure them

Functions I used

I've start whit two functions from user cybmeta :
just add a handle to result.

```
function theme_list_scripts() {

    global $wp_scripts;
    global $enqueued_scripts;
    $enqueued_scripts = array();
    foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) {
        $enqueued_scripts[] = $handle." | ".$wp_scripts->registered[$handle]->src;
    }
    return $enqueued_scripts;


}

function theme_list_styles() {

    global $wp_styles;
    global $enqueued_styles;
    $enqueued_styles = array();
    foreach( $wp_styles->queue as $handle ) {
        $enqueued_styles[] = $handle." | ".$wp_styles->registered[$handle]->src;
    }
    return $enqueued_styles;

}

add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'wpcustom_inspect_scripts_and_styles' );

function wpcustom_inspect_scripts_and_styles(){

    $loadet_list = array();

    $loadet_list["style"] = implode( " ; ",theme_list_styles() );

    $loadet_list["script"] = implode( " ; ",theme_list_scripts() );

    $_SESSION["front-end-list"] = implode("{}",$loadet_list);  


}

function front_loadet_files_list(){

    update_option( 'front_incl_list', $_SESSION["front-end-list"] );

}
```

in header file call after wp_head() befor colosing  head tag :

```
front_loadet_files_list();
```

in admin side in the file template where you wanna display :

get the data from option field in db

```
$loadet_list = prep_front_list("front-end-list");
```

call it for displaying

```
display_front_list($loadet_list["styles"]);

display_front_list($loadet_list["scripts"]);
```

the result[image: result view]

Comment: this is destroying the Stackexchange experience. Learn to effin' write code using the proper formatting. You might be causing way more problems than giving any solution by just throwing out completely non-formated code.

Comment: It looks like the only viable solution among all the answers. Though it would be good to get rid of using the $_SESSION variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you truly want to get a list of **all** styles, you can use the new *'script_loader_tag'* filter (Since Version 4.1).

The "wp_print_scripts" is:

> Called by admin-header.php and ‘wp_head’ hook.

i.e it doesn't show scripts in the footer.

**References:**

[Add Defer & Async Attributes to WordPress Scripts](https://matthewhorne.me/defer-async-wordpress-scripts/)

[wp_print_scripts](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_print_scripts/)

Comment: Do you maybe have an example how to use this?

Comment: Hi :)
Maybe this article can help
[Make Your Site Faster with Async and Deferred JavaScript: Introducing script_loader_tag](https://wpshout.com/make-site-faster-async-deferred-javascript-introducing-script_loader_tag)

Answer (score 0):

to get registered scripts you need function wp_scripts() and to get all enqueued styles you can use the function wp_styles().
Adding proper priority is also an important aspect to make sure to list the scripts after all of them were registered

something like this:

```
<?php

/*
Plugin name: My Plugin to list scripts and styles
*/


add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_plugin_print_styles',  PHP_INT_MAX );

function my_plugin_print_styles(){
    $wp_scripts = wp_scripts();
    $wp_styles = wp_styles();
    var_dump($wp_scripts);
    var_dump($wp_styles);
}
```