# How do I find stylesheet & javascript handles?

Tags: javascript

I am new to php and am just learning the basics. I'm dequeuing some stylesheets & scripts in WordPress using the following code:

```
function dequeue_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'handle' );
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_scripts' );
```

My question is how do I know what the script's / stylesheet's handle name is? Where can I find it?

I appreciate any help!! :)

Comment: You also could just scan the whole codebase for [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

Answer (score -1):

[WordPress provides a list of the scripts they enqueue in the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/#default-scripts-included-and-registered-by-wordpress). That's a good place to start.

Take a look at this question for a more complete answer: [How can I get a list of all enqueued scripts and styles?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233140/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-all-enqueued-scripts-and-styles)

Comment: Thank you @MikeNGarrett - and if they are custom? Eg from a plugin or a theme? Thanks!

Comment: Sure thing! See edited answer.