# How to override Bootstrap css with my child theme css in wordpress?

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

I am trying to load my site's child theme's css after Bootstrap CDN css in wordpress. I tried using these code but it doesn't work. The Bootstrap css is not overriden. What should I do to fix that?

```
function override_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap.min', 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'override_css' );
```

Comment: You can't override CSS that way. It will just load your CSS file _after_ bootstrap. You will have to override CSS declarations within your CSS file.

Comment: How are the parent theme's stylesheets enqueued?

Comment: Like this? I am not sure where to find

define( 'ASTRA_THEME_DIR', trailingslashit( get_template_directory() ) );
define( 'ASTRA_THEME_URI', trailingslashit( esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() ) ) );

isn't loading my css after the bootstrap the way to override it?

Comment: This answer talks about how to deregister a queued CSS - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/340770/109240